# How has this transformation been made?

Tags: calculus, analysis

This is the whole exercise.

$k\in Z$

$y'{}_{\pm}(k\pi) = \lim \limits_{\Delta x \to \pm0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}(arcsin(cos(k\pi+\Delta x))- arcsin(cosk\pi) $

= $\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to \pm0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}(arcsin((-1)^kcos\Delta x)-arcsin(-1)^k) $

= $\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to \pm0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}(-1)^{k+1} \frac{arcsin|sin \Delta x| }{\Delta x}$

= = $(-1)^{k+1} \lim \limits_{\Delta x \to \pm0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}\frac{arcsin|sin \Delta x| }{|sin \Delta x|}\lim\limits_{\Delta x \to \pm0}\frac{|sin \Delta x|}{\Delta x}$

= $(-1)^{k+1} \lim\limits_{\Delta x \to \pm0}\frac{|sin \Delta x|}{\Delta x}$

= $\pm(-1)^{k+1}$

Does anyone know how has this transformation been made?

= $\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to \pm0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}(arcsin((-1)^kcos\Delta x)-arcsin(-1)^k) $

= $\lim \limits_{\Delta x \to \pm0}\frac{1}{\Delta x}(-1)^{k+1} \frac{arcsin|sin \Delta x| }{\Delta x}$

Answer (score 0):

$arcsin(a)-arcsin(b)=arcsin(a*sqrt(1-b^2)-b*sqrt(1-a^2)$

Comment: I am aware of the formula, but when I enter alpha and beta , I get something which I can't transform into the result given below.